# Transition To Tab At SelectedIndex From ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, viewcontroller, xcode8

I'm trying to show a tabviewcontroller at a specific index,  from a viewcontroller that is outside of the tabviewcontroller.

For example,  I have this code:

```
let tabBar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar")
        self.show(tabBar!, sender: self)
```

This code shows the tabviewcontroller at the first index.  But when I try to select a certain index in the tabview and hide the tabbar It crashes.
So I tried the following:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
```

when the original viewcontroller is in the tabbarcontroller,  it works.  However when I move the view controller outside the tabbarcontroller it doesn't work.

I want to be able to show a specific index of a tabviewcontroller from an outside viewcontroller and hide the tabbar.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
let tabbar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") as? UITabBarController
        tabbar?.selectedIndex = 2
        tabbar?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        self.show(tabbar!, sender: self)
```